# Adjust the grid x-axis scale and y-axis scale in PairGrid method of seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, seaborn

I am struggling with getting the right x-axis and y-axis scale for my PairGrid plot of seaborn.
Code:

```
x = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue='species')
x = x.map_diag(plt.hist)
x = x.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
x = x.add_legend()
```

Graph:
[image]

Graph i want:
[image]

As you can see the graph 2 is much more informative with the proper and more suitable x-axis scale and y-axis scale. I already tried setting the different values of height but nothing gave me the results similar to the graph 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom plot is produced via the classic style.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("classic")
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")


x = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue='species')
x = x.map_diag(plt.hist)
x = x.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
x = x.add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Do i have to do `plt.style.use("classic")` everytime when i want to plot the graphs with this style? or is there a way to change the style to classic as default? without having to write this code in other jupyter notebooks before plotting any graph.

Comment: You can copy the content of the classic.mplstyle file to the [matplotlibrc-file](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file). I would not recommend doing this though.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the properties of *all* the subplots efficiently using `PairGrid.set()`. However, if you want to change each subplot more or less individually, you have no choice but to loop through each subplots and change their properties according to your need.

Here is what I would do in your case:

```
order = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
lims = [(4, 8.5), (1.5, 5), (0, 8), (-0.5, 3)]
tick_inc = [0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5]

sns.set()
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue="species", vars=order)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g = g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
g = g.add_legend()

loc = matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5)

for ax,(ylims, xlims),(yticks, xticks) in zip(g.axes.flat, 
                                              itertools.product(lims, lims),
                                              itertools.product(tick_inc, tick_inc)
                                             ):
    ax.set_xlim(xlims)
    ax.set_ylim(ylims)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(xticks))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(yticks))
```

[image]